# How do you send an embedded .dot template to word from a C# program?

Tags: c#, templates, ms-word, automation

I Have a template file embedded in a C# program but i need to store it in temp somehow so that word can read it. however, i don't know how to do that...

Comment: Just don't embed it.  There is little point, the extra code and the wasted virtual memory space is of no benefit.  If you want to have a single deploy-able file then that should be named setup.exe

Answer (score 0):

you can use `System.Io.Path.GetTempFileName()` to get a valid temp file path then you can save your dot in that location and open it with word.

Comment: But how would I save my dot in that location?  Maybe I'm missing something somewhere...

Comment: How is it embedded?  As a resource?